# Moving inline Javascript from component toa a Javascript file to be properly bundled by Stencil CLI

Tags: javascript, html, bigcommerce

How do I go about moving inline javascript from the html component to a separate js file so that it can be bundled and minified?

I'm editing BigCommerce and the latest Cornerstone theme.

the component is a button that adds 3 items to the cart by making a POST request to the storefront api (it works as intended, i just need to properly move it to be bundled)

```
<script>
    let lineItems = {
        "lineItems": [
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "productId": 103
            },
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "productId": 81
            },
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "productId": 77,
                "variantId": 11
            }
        ]
    };

    function postData(url = ``, cartItems = {}) {
        return fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(cartItems),
        }).then(function (response) {
            redirectToCart();
        });
    }

    function redirectToCart() {
        window.location = "/cart.php";
    }

    function showLoadingOverlay() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("loadingOverlay").forEach(x => x.style.display = "block");
    }

    function addBundleToCart() {
        let cartID = "{{cart_id}}"
        let url = `/api/storefront/cart`;

        if (cartID.length > 0) {
            // cart wasn't empty, update url
            showLoadingOverlay();
            url = `/api/storefront/carts/${cartID}/items`
        }
        postData(url, lineItems)
            .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
</script>

<button type="button" style="margin:0 auto;display:table; padding:20px; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; border: 3px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.164)"
    onclick="addBundleToCart()" id="addToCart">ADD BUNDLE TO CART</button>
```

I'm reading the documentation and it's not very clear what to do.
Am I supposed to create a custom template for this to work?( Brand, Category, Page, Product )

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to handle this and I'll start with how I'd recommend in this circumstance:

You can add the script portion of your code in Storefront > Script Manager and include it in the header of pages where the button will be placed. You may need to experiment with this as far as what will work best for you. With the remaining code for a button, you'll add this to the .html theme file where you want the button to appear, or anywhere HTML is accepted.

If it's necessary to add this to a bundled theme, you can add a .js file to the assets folder and reference that script in the HTML file(s) where the button is used. [I recommend taking a look at the Handlebars Helpers for injection found here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/handlebars-helpers-reference#handlebars-helpers-reference_injection), which gives details on using the CDN to efficiently reference your script.